# Does anyone know of a Java implementation similar to the .NET SoapFormatter

Tags: java, soap

I am looking for a library or code snippet to allow me to serialize and de serialize an object into a SOAP representation.  Similar to what the .NET SoapFormatter does but an implementation in Java.

I have looked on Google and web but so far I have been unable to find something which does it.  I know there is a namepsace in javax for SOAP, but again, if this holds what I need ton achieve it, I am looking for a little guidance code to show me an example or something.

TIA

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the **JAXB**(Java Architecture for XML Binding) and **SAAJ**(SOAP with Attachments API for Java).

Answer (score 0):

There are more web service implementations in Java than you could shake a stick at. There is no one way of doing this stuff.

Are you actually looking for a web service implementation, or just that one very specific task? There's no such thing as "SOAP representation", so I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: This is not for wweb services but something similar.  The objects which are created and exposed through web services I would like to use a formatter to serialize my object into the SOAP Representation of such.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by "SOAP representation"? That doesn't mean anything, SOAP is a protocol not a data format. Do you mean XML representation?

Comment: ok sorry by representation I meant using the schema used in SOAP, and yes ofcourse in XML.  With header, body etc... containing the object structure.  Thanks for your input